# Chrome: remote-debugging-port cannot work

Tags: google-chrome

I want to use the debugging mode for the google chrome, but it cannot work. Here is my command `/usr/bin/google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222`. After running it, the brower window pops out; however, I cannot find any server lauched after the command (`netstat -ntulp | grep 92`).

My enviroment is ubuntu 20.04 and the chrome version is Version 106.0.5249.119. Does anyone have suggestion?

I tried to use different profile on chrome, and it has the same situation still. However, when I switch to firefox, it works.